# Being a superuser, How can l see objects saved of other users?

Tags: python, django, django-2.2

Being a superuser, How can I access the objects saved in the database of other users.

Comment: Where are you having difficulty, exactly? Finding items for the logged-in user is not any different from finding items from another arbitrary user, surely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the superuser of your project you can use the built-in Django Admin to do this. By default the Django Admin can be found at 127.0.0.1:8000/admin .

Before you can see the tables you want to work with you will need to register them. You can read how to do this (and more information about the Django Admin in general) [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/admin/) .

You can also achieve this outside the scope of the Django Admin, but for that you haven't given us enough information. If you go this route you will need to make a start and then come back with more specific questions when you get stuck, showing what you have attempted up to that point.

Answer (score 0):

I  think you can go to 127.0.0.1:8000/admin

there you can choose the user you want to and check out their information